# Use SignalR-Client-Cpp with client certificate from windows cert store

Tags: c++, signalr, client-certificates

I am trying to communicate via SignalR with a server which requires client authentication with a certificate. Hence, i receive the following error when trying to start the connection:
*"connection could not be started due to: WinHttpSendRequest: 12044: A certificate is required to complete client authentication"*.

My program is in cpp, so i use the [SignalR-Client-Cpp](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp) which is integrate to my project via vcpkg.
My implementation is similar to the example in [readme.md](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp/blob/main/README.md#example-usage), you can use it as a base for a sample code.

My client-certificate is stored in Windows certificate store. How can I establish the connection with this certificate?